# Django - How to make reference to file in static files to a file in static files

Tags: python, django, file, static

I want to refer, let's say, an image, or a font in my static files to my `style.css` file which is also located within my staticfiles. How do I make this reference, since I can't load staticfiles within the staticfiles? Does staticfiles have a specified path to reach it or is there a way for me to set a path for it in order to access it. The other questions I saw that were alike this one were more for javascript files and found alternatives to it, which would not be viable in this case since I want to perform it on a cascading style sheet.

Comment: There is a setting called `STATIC_ROOT` which is the root directory of your static files.  In the admin shell : `from django.conf import settings; print(settings.STATIC_ROOT)`.

Comment: By definition of being static, these files don't have access to any of the context around your project. You would have to hard-code the (external) path to your static directory into the CSS.